# set an id for the youtube iframe with wp_oembed_get in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube, oembed

My theme uses wp_oembed_get for embedding youtube videos by iframe.

```
<?php echo wp_oembed_get( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wpex_post_video_oembed', true ) ); ?>
```

is it possible to give the iframe an id? I need it so use the youtube api.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the filter [`oembed_dataparse`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/19533/12615):

```
add_filter( 'oembed_dataparse', function( $return, $data, $url ){
    if( false === strpos( $return,'youtube.com' ) )
        return $return;

    $id = explode( 'watch?v=', $url );
    $add_id = str_replace( 'allowfullscreen>', 'allowfullscreen id="yt-'.$id[1].'">', $return );
    return $add_id;
}, 10, 3 );
```

This is a snapshot of the received parameters ("result" is showing another filter, `oembed_result`, but dataparse seems more complete):

> [image]